# Scrollbar CSS buttons not showing on macOS?

Tags: css

Could anyone have a look at my code and tell me why my buttons are not showing in my scrollbar on macOS? They work on Windows, perhaps I am overlooking a spelling mistake or something?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background:#eee;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #dfdfdf inset;
  border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background:#4B6A89;
  border: thin solid #4B6A89;
  border-radius:10px;
  height: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  background:#A1A7AC;
  border: thin solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background:#4B6A89;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/rwmYdPk.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/VAvOauT.png);
}
```

Comment: What browser and OS? Some browsers on some platforms simply don't have scroll bar buttons anymore. Most-notable macOS.

Comment: chrome on osx sierra

Comment: I just opened the site on a windows pc and see the icons now... thanks for the answer. thats a shame...

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure now. This seems to work on macOS: http://almaer.com/scrollbar/debug.html

Comment: Aha! Turns out I was mistaken, the buttons are still there, they are just hidden by default on macOS (because macOS does not normally have scroll buttons since 10.7+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS, the scrollbars are actually hidden by default. to make them visible, you need to make them `display: block;`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/rwmYdPk.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/VAvOauT.png);
}
```

Here's a working example, targeting both the `:start` and `:end` buttons in one selector remove the duplicate buttons.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background:#eee;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #dfdfdf inset;
  border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background:#4B6A89;
  border: thin solid #4B6A89;
  border-radius:10px;
  height: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  background:#A1A7AC;
  border: thin solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background:#4B6A89;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/rwmYdPk.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/VAvOauT.png);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
  display: block;
}

# Working Example (requires supported browser):
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <p style="width: 150%;">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I wouldn't have thought you could actually force the CSS to override the OS behaviour.

Comment: Awesome. thanks!  Only thing is, now I see both arrows on both sides of the scroll bar. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @IWI Probably, let me see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @IWI Ah, you need to add `:start` and `:end` to target specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

OSX scrollbars don't have buttons. That is why you are not seeing them in OSX and you are able to see them in Windows.